# nexus npm publish failed with error -4048

Tags: npm, nexus

I'm trying to publish my private module to a new setup nexus OSS 3.8.0-02 (running in sonatype/nexus3 docker container), and hit an error with `errno: -4048`.

My npm version is in: node v8.9.4 and npm  v5.6.0

I have already try to add my base64 encoded username and password in .npmrc which under my C:\Users\AHOU\ directory like so

```
always-auth=true
_auth="<generated base64>"
email=anselmhou.ps@gmail.com
prefix=C:\kits\npm
@ngpf:registry=http://<nexus server ip>:28081/nexus/repository/npm-public/
```

But whenever I try to run the command: `npm publish -ddd --registry http://<nexus server ip>:28081/nexus/repository/npm-private/`

It just gives the following error

```
npm sill mapToRegistry uri http://<nexus server ip>:28081/nexus/repository/npm-public/@ngpf%2fcore
npm verb publish registryBase http://<nexus server ip>:28081/nexus/repository/npm-public/
npm sill publish uploading C:\Users\AHOU\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9292-9e938c82\tmp\fromDir-f6e11f6c\package.tgz
npm verb stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\AHOU\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9292-9e938c82\tmp\fromDir-f6e11f6c\package.tgz'
npm verb cwd P:\PCCW Framework\workspace\ngpf\ngpf-core\dist
npm verb Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm verb argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "publish" "-ddd" "--registry" "http://    <nexus server ip>:28081/nexus/repository/npm-private/"
npm verb node v8.9.4
npm verb npm  v5.6.0
npm ERR! path C:\Users\AHOU\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9292-9e938c82\tmp\fromDir-f6e11f6c\package.tgz
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\AHOU\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9292-9e938c82\tmp\fromDir-f6e11f6c\package.tgz'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\AHOU\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9292-9e938c82\tmp\fromDir-f6e11f6c\package.tgz'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\AHOU\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9292-9e938c82\tmp\fromDir-f6e11f6c\package.tgz'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\Users\\AHOU\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\npm-9292-9e938c82\\tmp\\fromDir-f6e11f6c\\package.tgz' },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink     \'C:\\Users\\AHOU\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\npm-9292-9e938c82\\tmp\\fromDir-f6e11f6c\\package.tgz\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\AHOU\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\npm-9292-9e938c82\\tmp\\fromDir-f6e11f6c\\package.tgz' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm verb exit [ -4048, true ]
```

Any insights or suggestion would help.

Thank you in advance,
Anselm

Answer (score 8):

Answering my own question for people may hit the same as mine.

At the end, I found the error message is very misleading that has nothing do to with the file system. In fact this error is relating my npm publish does not have a valid for the registry that I'm trying to publish.

So my solution to this issue are:

1. Set the registry or scoped registry to the same registry that I'm
   trying to publish i.e. `http://<nexus server:ip?/nexus/repository/npm-private/`
2. `npm login --registry http://<nexus
   server:ip?/nexus/repository/npm-private/` to store the session.
3. For nexus side only, ensure the npm realm is also added.  By default it is not selected.
4. `npm publish`

For troubleshooting purpose, should also see the npm is publishing to the private repository and should have `npm verb request using bearer token for auth` during the `npm publish` request log.

Reference: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17450

Answer (score 3):

So The other answer is good that refers to setting the registry in your .npmrc file like

you need to do a login like

```
npm login --registry=http://IDK.com:8081/repository/yourRepo/
```

then you need to store yourself an admin/password/email. this will end up in your .npmrc file in your 'home' directory

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/   
@youreRegistry=http;//yourRegistry.com:8081/repository/thatRepoYouMadeInNexus/
```

^ Note the trailing forward slash

I'd also set:

```
always-auth=false
```

Another side note. Hop into your package.json for the code you're trying to push up and throw this entry into it:

```
"publishConfig": {
"yourRegistryName": "...your private registry..."
}
```

^note that if your registry has a '@' in the beginning or a special name, then make sure you don't just put 'registry'. otherwise this will just be 'registry': ...

For the people that have no idea what bearer tokens OR realms are and don't know why you're getting this error, OR why you're getting a Unauthorized 403 401. Check this out
[image]

Hope that helps. it's definitely what fixed my stuff. Worked immediately afterward.
References

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17450
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17450
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18309